# find and replace from command line unix

Tags: unix, replace

I have a multi line text file where each line has the format

```
..... Game #29832: ......
```

I want to append the character '1' to each number on each line (which is different on every line), does anyone know of a way to do this from the command line?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
cat file | sed -e 's/\(Game #[0-9]*\)/\11/'
```

Comment: UUOC.` sed -e 's/\(Game #[0-9]*\)/\11/' file`

Comment: Fair enough.  Some habits die hard.

Answer (score 6):

```
sed -i -e 's/Game #[0-9]*/&1/' file
```

`-i` is for in-place editing, and `&` means whatever matched from the pattern.  If you don't want to overwrite the file, omit the `-i` flag.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/ Game #\([0-9]*\):/ Game #1\1:/' yourfile.txt
```

Comment: doesn't work:

sed 's/ Game #([0-9]*):/ Game #1\1:/' handHistories1.txt


sed: -e expression #1, char 31: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: @Aly, that works with gnu sed. Depending on your sed version drop the backslash before the ( and )  or see if you have arguments to your sed version to enable that syntax

Comment: you had formatted your command as a quote, so the backslashes got eaten up.  I made it format like code.  The OP wants to *append* '1', by the way.

Answer (score 0):

GNU awk

```
awk '{b=gensub(/(Game #[0-9]+)/ ,"\\11","g",$0); print b }' file
```