# How to do a recursive find and replace from the command line?

Tags: bash, shell, readline

Is there a simple way to recursively search all files in a directory hierarchy for a term (e.g. `port`) and replace all occurrences of that term with another (e.g. `port-lookup`).

I have tried the suggestions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320215/find-and-replace-from-command-line-unix), but they are only applicable for a single file.

Comment: Thanks all! All the suggestions work great. I went with the `grep` answer based on the benefits mentioned by David C. Rankin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest (and arguably most pure and intuitive) way to achieve this is to perform a recursive file `grep` then pipe those file results to sed (via `xargs`) to handle the in-place substitution.

```
grep -r -l "port" | xargs -r -d'\n' sed -i 's/port/port-lookup/g'
```

> There is a comprehensive [community wiki answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files/112024#112024) on this topic that I would recommend reading over on the Unix & Linux exchange.

Comment: Well done with the initial call to `grep`, among other benefits it prevents the update to the file mod and access times that would be updated on all files if `sed -i` were used alone. While you can use a `find ... -execdir sed -i....` to search all files for `port` and make the changes, it would update file times on all, regardless if no changes were made.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/port/port-lookup/g' {} \;
```

If you don't want to change file modification time

```
grep -rl 'port' /search_in_this_dir | xargs sed -i 's/port/port-offset/g'
```

Comment: Good answer as well, but has the downside up updating all file modification times regardless of whether `port` was found/updated.

Comment: grep -rl 'port' /search_in_this_dir | xargs sed -i 's/port/port-offset/g'

Comment: On a Mac, you'll find not adding an argument after `-i` will result in unwanted files with an -e suffix. To remove these, run `find ./ -type f -exec sed -i '' -e 's/port/port-lookup/g' {} \;` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a recent version of bash (>4)

```
shopt -s globstar
sed -i 's/port/port-lookup/g' **/*
```

Comment: This is a neat Bash 4 feature that I need to make a note of!

Comment: It's also built in to zsh, which is where I started using it first. I'm always a bit disappointed when I log in to bash 3 and this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just 1 command line: `msr -rp dir1,dir2,file1,fileN -x port -o port-lookup -R`

The above command recusively search and replaces plain text `port` to `port-lookup` in files.

- If you want to **preview replacing result**, remove `-R`
- If you want to preview and summarize files list and count/distribution, add `-l`
- If you want to backup the changed files, add `-K` like `-K -R` or `-RK`.
- Ignore case add `-i` like  `-i -x` or `-ix`.
- If you want to use `C++`/`C#`/`Java`/`Scala` **Regex** syntax, use `-t` instead of `-x`.
- Filter file name like: include `-f "\.(xml|java|cpp)$"` , exclude `--nf "\.(so|a|lib|dll|obj)$"`
- Filter directory name like: include `-d "src"` ,  exclude `--nd "^(target|\.git)$"`
- Filter file size range like: `--s1 1`/`--s1 1B` with/or `--s2 1.20MB`
- Filter file last write time range like: `--w1 2017-08-01` with/or `--w2 "2017-08-12 11:20:30"`

More usages about find and replace file or pipe just see my open project https://github.com/qualiu/msr (`msr.exe` / `msr.gcc*` / `msr.cygwin` are in the `tools` directory). Built-in usage and exmaples just run the exe. Docs like [performance comparision with **findstr** and **grep**](https://github.com/qualiu/msr/blob/master/perf/summary-full-Cygwin-comparison.md) .